# Finding a function whose graph passes through two given points, given its (constant) second derivative

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> It is known that $y(x)$ passes through the points $(0,2)$ and $(1,4)$. Solve for $y(x)$ if the second derivative is:
>      $$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = 1 .$$

The answer is:

> $$y = \frac{1}{2}(x^2 + 3x)-2.$$

I've tried integrating both sides of equation... it's probably not the answer. What do I need to do? Is there a technique?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First find $y=f(x)$:$$
\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = 1 \implies \frac{dy}{dx} = x+C \implies y = \frac 12 x^2+Cx+K
$$Next we substitute our points into $(x,y)$:$$
2 = \frac{1}{2}(0)^2+C(0) +K \\
4 = \frac 12 (1)^2+C(1) + K
$$These equations give us:$$
2=K \\
4 = \frac 12 +C+K
$$Solving for $C$ and $K$ will give us our particular $y=f(x)$ solution.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Assuming that $y$ is a polynomial, since you only have three conditions, it must be a quadratic (since the second derivative is a constant). So $$y=A+B x+C x^2$$ $y''=2C$ implies $C=\frac 12$. Now, compute $A$ and $B$ in order the function goes through the two points.

Comment: (Of course, constant second derivative already implies that $y(x)$ is a polynomial.)

Comment: @Travis. For sure, you are right ! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Once integrate

$$ y' = x + c $$

Again integrate

$$ y = x^2/2 + c\, x + d $$

Plug in the given points (0,2), (1,4} to find out $c,d.$